# Appending values processed by JS to a textarea to be sent in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a school project, but I've ran into a problem I don't know how to solve.

Me and my group are working on a recipe bank where users are able to upload their own recipes. I want the user to upload the recipe itself in stages.
Something like

1. Boil some water.
2. Put eggs in the boiling water
3. let boil for 5-6 minutes."

The html:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="recipe">
    <p><input type="text" name="name "placeholder="name"/></p>
    <p><div class="recipe_showing"></div></p>
    <textarea name="recipe_data"  class="recipe_data" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    <p><input type="text" class="recipe_part" placeholder="part of the recipe"/>
    <input type="button" class="recipe_enter" value="enter"/></p>
<more form tags and etc>
```

I know the over use of `<p>` tags, We're currently working on the functionality of the code, optimization will be second.

Here is the js code we use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var recipe_logg_count=0;
    $(".recipe_enter").click(function() {
        if ($('.recipe_part').val() == null) {
            alert('please write down the first part of the recipe');
        }
        else {
            recipe_logg_count++;
            $('.recipe_showing').append(recipe_logg_count + '. ' + $('.recipe_part').val()+ '</br>');
            $('.recipe_data').append('<p>'+ recipe_logg_count + '. ' + $('.recipe_part').val()+'</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not showing the content of the textarea to the user, I'm using a separate div for that.
As you can see, I'm trying to simply append the values taken from "recipe_part" to the textarea, but this doesn't work.

I've tried removing the `<p>` tag that i append in the beginning, and that seem to work fine then. But I need to have the `<p>` tag for styling the recipe on the page it's shown on.

Is there a way to send the contents of the text are even if there is other html tags inside of it?

Comment: Forgot to add, in handler.php $_POST the key recipe_data is empty. Completely empty

Comment: You might want to use a `submit` button when sending it to the server... Also your `style` is incorrectly closed (well, _not_) on one of the text areas and your last two inputs lack the closing `/`.

Comment: You may want to mention that your JavaScript is jQuery, that way you can attract more jQuery fans to help you out.

Comment: @somethinghere That was just me messing up when copying the code, I've tried to make it clearer now also, there are more form tags and such. we are using a button to submit it in the end of the form.

Comment: @Sinto Yes, I'm trying to append to both 'recipe_showing and 'recipe_data'

Comment: needs `});` at the end of jQuery block to close `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: @PedroLobito That's me again, missing to copy something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `append` when applied to a `textarea` appears to just silently ignore text with tags in. You can get around this by using `$('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + ...)` instead, however allowing user submission of html tags is generally discouraged anyway since without careful sanitation it'll lead to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not insert paragraphs inside a textarea (not sure if it's even possible). Instead, I would have 2 tables inside mysql database, one named "recipes" and the other named "steps". Each recipe has an auto increment id, and each step is connected to a recipe by that id. While user is inserting steps on each submit of a step I would do an ajax call that would insert that step into a database, show it to the user inside this extra div you're using for recipe preview and empty the input so that user can begin inserting next step.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can append text within the textarea. You should be able to append text within the textarea with val();

You could try to use .val() function

```
var textData =  $('.recipe_data').val();
var textShowing =  $('.recipe_showing').val();
$('.recipe_data').val(textData + recipe_logg_count + '. ' + $('.recipe_part').val()+"\n\r");
$('.recipe_showing').val(textShowing + recipe_logg_count + '. ' + $('.recipe_part').val()+"\n\r");
```

Or else use js

```
var enterBtn = document.getElementById('recipe_enter');
var recipeData = document.getElementById('recipe-data');
var recipeShowing = document.getElementById('recipe-showing');
var recipeData_value = '';
var recipeShowing_value = '';
enterBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var rpart = document.getElementById('recipe_part').value;
    recipeData_value += recipe_log_count + '. ' + rpart + "\n\r";
    recipeShowing_value += recipe_logg_count + '. ' + rpart + "\n\r";
    recipeData.value = recipeData_value;
    recipeShowing.value = recipeShowing_value;
});
```

[JQuery]
Save the previous text in variables outside the function scope and append to these variables and then add these variables as values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var recipe_logg_count=0;

var recipe_data = '';
var recipe_showing = '';

$(".recipe_enter").click(function() {
    var recipe_part = $('.recipe_part').val();
    if (recipe_part == null) {
        alert('please write down the first part of the recipe');
    }
    else {
        recipe_logg_count++;
        recipe_data += recipe_logg_count + '. ' + recipe_part + "\n\r";
        recipe_showing += recipe_logg_count + '. ' + recipe_part +"\n\r";
        $('.recipe_data').val(recipe_data);
        $('.recipe_showing').val(recipe_showing);
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that .html() could be possible, but how exactly might it be a security risk?

Comment: Updated my answer, html does not apply here. Html() could create js-injection risk

Comment: I've tried this, but it still won't add anything inside the textarea :/

Comment: Try again, updated the quotes. If jquery does not work try only js and add id fields to recipe data and part

Comment: @Nitin I've looked through my code and saw that I had spelled a part wrong, now it sort of works. The only problem is that is only adds one element. If I add "Boil water" and then try to add "add salt" The only thing that shows up is '<p>2. add salt</p>'

Comment: It is replacing the previous text. You must save the previous text in a variable first and then prepend this variable to the next string

Comment: I have added an example above

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a few thing now, and realized I could attack the problem with php. If i do like this:

```
"$('.recipe_data').append(recipe_logg_count + '. ' + $('.recipe_part').val()+ ':');"
```

This allows me to append the value.
After that, I can easily do

```
$recipe_parts = explode(':', $recipe_data);
foreach($recipe_parts as $part){
print "<p>".$part."<p/>";
}
```